# Bug when creating more than 5 alias in column names in MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, join, mariadb

I am trying to get all the "Title" columns from different tables.  Idealy I would want to get all the "Title" values from the different tables in the same result so I can then write them up one by one in PHP.

My Tables are as such :

```
CREATE TABLE `TaxoGenre` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Titre` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Tri` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

My sql looks like that :

```
$sql = "
SELECT TD.Titre, TSD.Titre, TC.Titre, TOR.Titre, TSO.Titre, TF.Titre, TG.Titre
FROM TaxoDivision TD, TaxoSousDivision TSD, TaxoClasse TC, TaxoOrdre TOR,
TaxoSousOrdre TSO, TaxoFamille TF, TaxoGenre TG";

$stmt = $dbPDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$groups = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$groups = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt->closeCursor();

var_dump($groups);
```

When excuted on my php page the request returns a 503 Service Unavailable error..  No php error that I can debug.

When I do it directly on the MariaDB server in phpMyAdmin I get the results, but in 7 differents columns with the same "Titre" name which is not what I would like.  I would like that all the results be appended to each other.

I am thinking the error could come from the columnn names having the same name so I tried :

```
SELECT TD.Titre AS Division, TSD.Titre AS SousDivision,
TC.Titre AS Classe, TOR.Titre AS Ordre, TSO.Titre SousOrdre,
TF.Titre AS Famille, TG.Titre AS Genre 
FROM TaxoDivision TD, TaxoSousDivision TSD, TaxoClasse TC, TaxoOrdre
TOR, TaxoSousOrdre TSO, TaxoFamille TF, TaxoGenre TG
```

This even make My direct SQL request go bad..  *#2006 - MySQL server has gone away*

But as soon as I limit my alias names to 5 whatever the order, it works in my direct SQL tests, with the two remaining columns named just Titre. ex :

```
SELECT TD.Titre, TSD.Titre,
TC.Titre AS Classe, TOR.Titre AS Ordre, TSO.Titre SousOrdre,
TF.Titre AS Famille, TG.Titre AS Genre 
FROM TaxoDivision TD, TaxoSousDivision TSD, TaxoClasse TC, TaxoOrdre
TOR, TaxoSousOrdre TSO, TaxoFamille TF, TaxoGenre TG
```

**Is there a limit to the number of custom name we can give to columns?????**

I know I could just get one table at a time and add the results to an array in php, But I am really curious of the cause of that error and **How we can in simple SQL combine results from different table in one array of results....**  Thanks for your expertise as always!!

Working on PHP 8.2 and Database is 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve-log

**EDIT : I confirm that this code works.  But is there MySQL simple ways?**

```
$names = [];
$tables = [];
$tables[] = "Division";
$tables[] = "SousDivision";
$tables[] = "Classe";
$tables[] = "Ordre";
$tables[] = "SousOrdre";
$tables[] = "Famille";
$tables[] = "Genre";


foreach ($tables as $tbName) {
    $sql = "SELECT Taxo$tbName.Titre FROM Taxo$tbName";
    $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $groups = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $groups = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $names = array_merge($names,$groups);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}


var_dump($names);
```

**EDIT 2**

To resume my main goal imagine 2 tables :

Table 1 : TaxoDivision

```
ID    Title

1     Eucomycota
2     Agaricomycota
```

Table 2 : TaxoSousDivision

```
ID    Title

1     Agaricomycetes
2     Eucomycetes
```

AND So on for the seven tables

How can I get

```
Title

Eucomycota
Agaricomycota
Agaricomycetes
Eucomycetes
…
```

I dont need the IDs and the IDs are only unique in each tables but no relation between the tables

Comment: You're missing the joining conditions. So you're creating a full cartesian product between all the rows in all the tables, and the server is running out of memory.

Comment: I'm not sure why the aliases make a difference, though.

Comment: @Barmar OK Thanks, but can you tell me what joining would I need?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM TaxoDivision TD JOIN TaxoSousDivision TSD ON TD.ID = TSD.TD_ID JOIN TaxoClasse TC ON TD.ID = TC.TD_ID ...`. You didn't show the other tables, so I had to guess on the foreign key names.

Comment: Please make sure you understand how the basics of SQL JOINs work. Any half-decent SQL tutorial, course or book will explain it to you quite early on.

Comment: some sample data and the results you want for that sample data would help enormously

Comment: @ysth I added a simple edit

Comment: You only have 2 tables in your sample data, the original query joins 7 tables. And the table names are completely different. Please post sample data that matches the query.

Comment: It looks like you actually want `UNION`, not `JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

OK Thanks to @Barmar, UNION is what I was searching for..  This works.

```
SELECT TaxoDivision.Titre FROM TaxoDivision
UNION SELECT TaxoSousDivision.Titre FROM TaxoSousDivision
UNION SELECT TaxoClasse.Titre FROM TaxoClasse
UNION SELECT TaxoOrdre.Titre FROM TaxoOrdre
UNION SELECT TaxoSousOrdre.Titre FROM TaxoSousOrdre
UNION SELECT TaxoFamille.Titre FROM TaxoFamille
UNION SELECT TaxoGenre.Titre FROM TaxoGenre;
```

I use a lot of JOIN but first time I needed UNION!

Thanks

But I am still curious about the 5 alias..  but I probably just demanded too much to the server because of he cartesian error

Comment: Note that by default, UNION is UNION DISTINCT, which will eliminate any duplicates.  This can slow the query down; if you don't expect any duplicates or you want them to be included, say UNION ALL instead

Comment: Ok thanks @ysth I knew it only kept non-duplicates, but did not know that it would be slower.  But in my case there is one or two duplicates so better leave like this